# Ionic2 Firebase 3.2 Angularfire2 2.0.0-beta.2 Auth not working when testing on device

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, ionic-view, angularfire2

When I run ionic serve --lab everything works fine in the browser. I can do auth operations with email and password. When I try and test on a device through ionic upload, or build on android, the app isnt authenticating correctly. I can still connect to firebase if I hard code the Url of a list or object but can't get the data through my auth login. Its worth noting that when I emulate in the browser I get "The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working." Not sure if its related to my issue because it still allows me to login from the browser and I am not using any of those, just auth.login(email, password). Also when I debug the app from my device through chrome I get "Uncaught Error: "location.protocol" must be http or https ". Does anyone know how I may be able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Popup and redirect operations are only currently supported in http and https  environments. Check this thread on how to sign in or link with popup in Ionic/Cordova: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/cordova$20facebook/firebase-talk/mC_MlLNCWnI/DqN_8AuCBQAJ

Comment: question refers to what to do in the particular case when only email auth is being used. I am having the same problem as described above, Popup and Redirect has nothing to do with the question, as these methods are not being used.